# Up-to-date numbers on memory latency?

Tags: memory, x86, gpu, cpu-architecture, gpgpu

I'm looking for an up-to-date reference on what typical (register)/cache/memory latencies are on modern x86_64 hardware. Preferably if something similar exists for GPU that would be great as well.

I found the following link from 2016, https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/memory-performance-in-a-nutshell.html but ideally I'd like something from the 2020's.

Often, memory latency is specified in cycles. I assume this means that if the latency is 10 cycles and I have a 1GHz CPU, then the latency would be `10 cycles / 10^9 cycles per second = 10^-8 seconds`?

I'm really not looking to do a deep dive into the architecture. Rough numbers are completely fine.

Comment: See [this](https://www.uops.info/cache.html) for the cache latencies. The linked plots will also tell you the memory latencies in core cycles. But this is variable. The frequency of a CPU is not fixed.

Comment: https://www.7-cpu.com/ has some memory latency microbenchmark numbers for some recent CPUs such as a 4c8t Ice Lake mobile (https://www.7-cpu.com/cpu/Ice_Lake.html) and Apple M1 (https://www.7-cpu.com/cpu/Apple_M1.html), along with cache and TLB geometry.  e.g. M1 big-core (Firestorm) they list as 18 cycles + 91 ns .  (That seems pretty high, but is in line with the LPDDR4 numbers from Ice Lake, although the non-LP DDR4 numbers from ICL were RAM Latency = 42 cycles + 64 ns instead of 42c + 87 ns.  Breakdown into (core / uncore L3) cycles plus fixed time reflects a fixed memory clock freq.

Comment: Thank you, both of these are interesting.